# saving state at client Side or application variable in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I have a website in which User logs in through FB and Gmail, If Mr A comes through Facebook and logs in successfully on the website, then supposehe logs out and logs in through Gmail, I wouldn't be treating him as a new user but I will assign the Old User ID to him because this is the same guy.
So the solution I thought was to place a cookie on user computer and check if he is existing user so that we will not register him again, but issues with cookie is may be user clears/turn off browser cookies, logs in from  other PC .I dont know what could be the best scenerio to handle this situation?
**Another example could while logging into Stackoverflow I can use Gmail login or Yahoo.etc**
Any helps

Comment: Use OpenID, it will handle all this for you... http://openid.net/add-openid/

Comment: @BenCarey I already implemented Google and fb sign in, I could consider something int future but for now I am already existing login

Comment: The google email account matchs with facebook email address?

Comment: You can postpone the expire date of the cookie, but that still doesn't seem right: just because two login happens on the same computer does not naturally mean these are the same person. Could you give your users an option to "merge" different foreign accounts? E.g. "Hi, I'm abc from facebook. I also have a gmail account that is abc@gmail.com, treat that as me too.".

Comment: @rogeriolino it could be different

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this is you have two options:

### Cookies

You could set a cookie on the clients machine that effectively links the two accounts as you have suggested...

#### Disadvantages

1. If you login onto a different computer with a different account, it will not link the two accounts.
2. There is not really anyway of telling that the person that logged in via Facebook, and the person that logged in via Google are actually the same person. The only way you can tell is via email address but this could cause confusions.

### OpenID

Open ID is a service that effectively allows you to login using any of your 'main' accounts including Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Microsoft, AOL etc...

See [here](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/) for more information on OpenID.

It does exactly what you are trying to do, but it does it for you...

I appreciate that you may have already written the login for Facebook and Google on your site, but the stress of managing that and handling the bugs are far outweighed by the time it would take to implement an OpenID library on your site.

See these PHP libraries for implementing the OpenID functionality on your site:

- http://janrain.com/openid-enabled/
- http://gitorious.org/lightopenid
- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3290-PHP-Authenticate-users-with-OpenID-single-sign-on.html

Integrating this into your site really wont take very long and it will remove the stress of having to handle the cookies etc from a custom login...

Comment: can I get my facebook friends and make API calls after logging through OpenID (facebook)?

Comment: @user1765876 Yes you can but you need to set up a Facebook App and get an access token to access the API